# Where in the "MyLocation" widget in ArcGIS Online Web AppBuilder

Tags: arcgis-online, widget

I'm trying to build a simple webapp which shows my device's location as well as a few other layers. Although I can find information about the "MyLocation" Widget on the web, the tool can't be found in the widget list. The "MyLocation" Widget show the current location of the device. I want to

How can I add this tool to a map when its not listed in the add-widget section?

Comment: What theme are you using? I see half the themes have it by default on the map, and the others have it as an option to select from the widget list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location widget is apart of the actual map widget and can be enabled from the map widgets settings pane along with select, home, etc.